# Action Text displaying html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I'm using Action Text in order to create articles and display well the content of it.
But I have a problem, when I create my article then display the content it's showing the HTML tags.
Here :
[image]

Here is my code :

articles/show.html.erb :

```
<%= @article.body %>
```

application.scss:

```
@import "trix/dist/trix";
@import "./actiontext.scss";
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<%= f.rich_text_area :body, height: "300px", width:"300px" %>
<%= end %>
```

application.js :

```
//= require actiontext
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

actiontext.scss:

```
.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }

    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }

  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone got any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know why action text are showing the HTML balise but maybe using [SanitizeHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) would help you to remove the balises.

We use it in our project after having a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked I just added <%= sanitize @article.body%>