# ActionText is displaying with html tags when displayed in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, richtextbox, trix, actiontext

I tried looking around but couldnt find an answer to this. The only post I found that resembles my problem is here: [Action Text displaying html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65916336/action-text-displaying-html-tags) However when I try to use the sanetize method I just get another error "no implicit conversion of ActionText::RichText into String" so I would really just like to fix the original problem of the html tags displaying to begin with.  Here is what it currently looks like:
[image]

Added `has_rich_text` to comment module:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  validates :body, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  has_rich_text :body
end
```

Added imports into application.js:

```
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
```

Added import to actiontext.scss:
`@import "trix/dist/trix";`

Added import to application.css.scss:
`@import "./actiontext.scss";`

Added rich text area to form:

```
 <%= form_with model: [@post, @comment], local: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.rich_text_area :body, class: 'form-control greyh' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Comment', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
 <% end %>
```

And finally here is how it's being displayed:

```
<%="[#{comment.created_at.strftime("%I :%M %p")}] #{comment.user.username}: #{comment.body}" %>
```

I am not sure what else to try at this point . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not 100% clear on the desire. Do you want to strip the tags? `comment.body.to_plain_text`; Or you want the tags actually rendered as part of html? `sanitize(comment.body.to_s)`.

Comment: I would like it to display as rich text in the comment section. But currently it's displaying with html tags instead of rich text.

Comment: Okay I provided you with options for both. Please feel free to try them